# React Native connect manipulate data from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, react-native

Hy i am new with React Native, i already make web app using MERN then i want to make mobile app using React Native, this mobile app will connect and manipulate data in a database from my web app (MongoDb). How can my mobile app can connect and manipulate data from my database in mongodb ?

Comment: I'm not sure why React Native would be much different in this case? In a MERN stack, the React frontend makes requests to your Node/Express backend, which then manipulates the database. A React Native frontend would do the same thing.

Comment: thx Joel for the reply, i dont know how React Native and MongoDb can work together. from information i get React Native using firebase as a databases.

Comment: @JoelRummel i am new with react native, i am sorry because my misunderstanding . so you mean i can connect using API to my backend to manipulate data from my database (MongoDb).

Comment: Neither React nor React Native frontends should be directly "using" a database in a MERN stack. Rather, they should simply make the same calls to the same Node/Express backend. Pretty much any frontend language/framework can make use of any backend, as long as it can make network requests.